# Div expanding from left of bootstraps container to the right of the screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling to find a solution to a problem that I have.

What I'm trying to achieve is a DIV that is inside bootstrap's .container to span full width to the right of the container (till it hits the screen), but be INSIDE container on the left.

Example code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="extended-div"></div>
</div>
```

I just want the extended-div to stick to the left of CONTAINER element, and span all the way to the right of the screen from there (Outside of the container).

I'm attaching an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Normally, if the box was only BG colour etc etc, I'd either go with box-shadow or :after methods, but this won't work here.

[Here's what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RtRK.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add some code to add more information?

Comment: Added a code example.

Comment: Nothing yet answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving position absolute to the extended div and you have not properly closed your class tag for container

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="extended-div"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nothing yet answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

First close your class tag for `container` properly.
Increase the width of child div as your need.

```css
.container{
   background-color:red;
   }
.extended-div
{
  background-color:green; 
  width:110%;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="extended-div">
        <h1>
          jfksdjfksdjfds
        </h1>
        <h1>
           overflow div sssssssssssssssssssddsssssssdddddddddddd
        </h1>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing yet answered my question.